# Referencing cells from Sheet 1 (Legend) to Sheet 2 (Allocation)

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use VBA for my final year project. However, I am having some difficulties.

I am trying to use Excel VBA to reference a sheet that I have coded with department names that have their own specific colours. For instance, department "CLR" with red colour. I am hoping that if I were to go to another sheet, and use the drop down list to select the department I want, it will change according to colour I have set from my first sheet.

For the sheet that I have coded, I will be putting below as well as picture files. 
Do guide me along as I am weak in VBA.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Set i = Intersect(Target, Range("A1:Z10000"))
    If Not i Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Target
            Case "CLR": NewColor = 3
            Case "CTS": NewColor = 4
            Case "OMS": NewColor = 5
            Case "ENT": NewColor = 6
            Case "O&G": NewColor = 7
            Case "HND": NewColor = 8
            Case "SUR_ONCO": NewColor = 9
            Case "NES": NewColor = 10
            Case "OTO": NewColor = 11
            Case "PLS": NewColor = 12
            Case "BREAST": NewColor = 13
            Case "UGI": NewColor = 14
            Case "HPB": NewColor = 15
            Case "VAS": NewColor = 16
            Case "H&N": NewColor = 17
            Case "URO": NewColor = 18
            Case "OPEN": NewColor = 19
        End Select
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = NewColor


    End If


End Sub
```

Update 2 : Filtering Table

I decided to use a textbox to filter my data when I type in my department. However, I experienced some trouble whenever I type in the department name. Could you possibly help me with my problem?

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

    Dim Text

    Text = TextBox1.Value

    If Text <> "" Then
        Sheet2.Range("C7:AV26").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Text,_", VisibleDropDown:=False

    Else:
        Sheet2.AutoFilterMode = False

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: you should probably use conditional formatting, not VBA for this.

Comment: you should also consider not using VBA for the filtering.. it's just not how excel is supposed to work

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a couple assumptions about your example, but if it's not exactly what you need I'm hoping you can adapt it. I set up the following range:

[image]

Then, on the `Allocation` worksheet, the single drop-down cell used Data Validation on `Cell C2` to validate using a `List` from `=Legend!C2:C6`:

[image]

My assumption was that you wanted whatever color you chose for each item on your `Legend` worksheet to be used for the setting of the drop-down cell on the `Allocation` worksheet. In your code, you've hard-coded the colors into VBA -- meaning if you wanted to change the colors, you'd have to modify your code. My example below will find the user's selection in the drop-down and grab the current color of that cell to apply it to the drop-down cell. This way, if you want to re-do the colors you don't have to modify your VBA code at all.

The `Worksheet_Change` event code for the `Allocation` worksheet looks like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$C$3" Then
        Dim legendWS As Worksheet
        Dim legendCell As Range
        Set legendWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Legend")

        Set legendCell = legendWS.Range("C2:C6").Find(Target.Value)
        If Not legendCell Is Nothing Then
            Target.Interior.Color = legendCell.Interior.Color
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Omg!! Thank you so much!! I will try it out and if i have any questions, possible to ask u in the comments?

Comment: from ur code, you put target.address = "$C$3" , does it mean that whenever i change the department name at that cell, it will change the colour according to my legend sheet? What I would like to know is if i am able to change the target address to a range of cells  instead of just having it to one cell?

Comment: Yes, you can change the target address to any range you need. What changes in that range are you trying to detect? Or do you want to change the background color of that range based on the drop downstairs selection?

Comment: so i have this table in my excel and i am hoping that all the columns for the various "dept" labelled in the sheet follows the colour according to my legend sheet. It similar to the code you provided me, but in a larger range. Also, i was wondering if filtering is possible? For instance, filter the entire table only showing the department that i want to show?                               [Link1] http://imgur.com/1r8Sw59

Comment: If you change the very first `If` statement in my code example to use your `Intersect` logic, then the rest of the code should work just fine over the entire range and will update the color of the changed cell. You ca also filter the table either with the `Data-->Filter` on the Data ribbon, or possibly using VBA if you think that's necessary. It all depends on what you're filtering and how to accomplish that for the user.

Comment: i am still abit confused on the intercept function. Is it possible to explain to me more about it? Sorry for the inconvenienced caused 

Comment: Use the `Intercept` function inside of the `Worksheet_Change` event to determine if, when a user makes a change in *any* cell on that worksheet changes, if that changed cell is within a range of interest. For example (from your linked image), if you wanted to detect changes to any Dept for Specialized OTs, your VBA would check for `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C10:L38")) is Nothing Then`. ONLY if the user changed a cell in that range would the code then look at the Target and see if one of your list values was set and then change the color.

Comment: Thanks @PeterT , it definitely helped out in my learning journey for VBA and the codes work for my project!!              Now i am trying to look into filtering. Isit possible to clear contents of the table like everytime i filter it? I believe that is VBA? Moreover, if i select a department like 'CTS' at cell G4, i would want the whole table which is "C10:L38" to be filtered only showing CTS. I heard something about advanced filters but i am not sure whether if it is applicable in this case

Comment: It's all dependent on what your use case is for the display. An advanced filter may not be what you are looking for. When the user selects `CTS` in cell G4, do you want on the CTS cells to show in your OTS range? Or the CTS cells and the Week cell next to it? Do you want certain rows or columns to be hidden if they don't contain CTS, or for the table to stay the same size/shape but cause non-CTS to go blank (or perhaps better yet, to change the text color to a light gray)? You have to more thoroughly think out what you want to happen and try it. Then maybe open another question here if needed.

Comment: Hi @PeterT , sorry to bother you again but when i tried to filter based on department using textbook, i realised that it is not working. Could you possibly help me?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by department using textbook? I see in your other question that you've gotten some help on filtering. Did that solve your problem?

Comment: Woops textbox. Not really, still had problems filtering when i type in the department. I'm not rlly sure where i have done wrong

Comment: I don't think the `AutoFilter` will work in your particular case. The way it's supposed to work is to "hide/show" certain rows that meet a specific criteria: in the simplest case it would hide/show all rows with `Mon` in Column A. You're thinking that the `AutoFilter` will search for a department "e" in **any** of the cells in your range, then hide everything else. `AutoFilter` is capable of hiding an entire row in a table, but not blanking out everything else in that range. I think you'll have to rethink your approach.